# Django 1.10 or later: base.html override not working

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am creating a site in Django with a custom view, and want to link to that view on the admin page. But even though I've followed the directions to override in Documentation or Youtube, but i won't show the changes in the overide file.

```html
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Django site admin')    }}{% endblock %}

 {% block branding %}
 <h1 id="site-name"><a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">Test</a></h1>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

My **base.html** in ratonix\templates\admin

Map tree:

- └─ratonix
  ----└── ratonix
  ----------└── settings.py
  ----------└── views.py
  ----------└── urls.py
  --- └── templates
  -----------└── admin
  - ------------  └── base.html

  - └── manage.py

Templates folder in the same folder as **manage.py**

This is my current **settings.py**:

```js
"""
Django settings for ratonix project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

import pymysql
import os
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()


from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-SECRET SORRY!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'ratonix',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ratonix.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates/')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ratonix.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ratonix_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
     
        
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/xampp/htdocs/ratonix/ratonix/static/'), )
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

I've restarted the server, as well as used different browsers, and none of my changes show up.

Am I doing something wrong anywhere, or are the instructions given by the tutorial just plain incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of `INSTALLED_APPS` affects the override order.

If you have `templates/admin/base.html` in the `ratonix` app, then `ratonix` must come before `django.contrib.admin` in `INSTALLED_APPS` for that template to be used.

Since you also have `DIRS` in your `TEMPLATES` configuration, you could also use `<PROJECT>/templates/admin/base.html`, and that would be used; [per the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/overriding-templates/),

> If you have app and project templates directories that both contain overrides, the default Django template loader will try to load the template from the project-level directory first. In other words, DIRS is searched before APP_DIRS.

Note the preferred customization point for the admin is `admin/base_site.html`.

Comment: Thanks! change the order for overide and change filename did the trick!